# How to report results of a polynomial regression with a discrete independent variable

Tags: linear-model, linear, polynomial, quadratic-form, statsmodels

I have been recently trying to fit a linear model to my data. The dependent variable is continuous and the independent variable is numeric and discrete. When I first test the assumptions concerning the data structure in order to run a linear regression I observe violations of the assumptions of linearity and normality. The relationship between my independent variable and my dependent variable is nonlinear, and residuals are not normally distributed:

Here a plot of the relationship between y and x (plus a line of predicted values using a linear regression):
[image]

Here some plots to test linearity and normality assumptions:
[image]

After that, I tried unsuccessfully to linearize the relationship between the variables by transforming the data (by doing log(y); log(x); sqrt(y).  etc...), but I did not find any transformation that satisfactorily increased the linearity.

Thus, I decided not to run a prototypical linear regression but a polynomial regression, using a quadratic polynomial. The model that I have run is as follows:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
summary(model)
```

By running the polynomial regression I obtain the next residuals and coefficients:

> ```
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -2.30465 -0.65161  0.01504  0.60506  1.95826 
>
> Coefficients:
>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)  2.3617770  0.0036701  643.52   <2e-16 ***
> x           -0.0508341  0.0014057  -36.16   <2e-16 ***
> I(x^2)      -0.0062881  0.0001141  -55.12   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.8663 on 739197 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.1781,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.1781 
> F-statistic: 8.007e+04 on 2 and 739197 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

Here a plot of the polynomial fitting the data:
[image]

Some questions:

1) By running a linear regression (y~x) I get R2=0.1747. When running the quadratic regression I get R2=0.1781. Giving this R2 and giving that there is a violation of the linearity assumption: should I keep the quadratic regression as a better fit of my data?

2) In a prototypical linear regression (y = b0 + b1*x) the way to read the output of x (our predictor effect or effect size) is quite straightforward: "for every increase of x by 1, the effect of x on y is b1". However, for the quadratic regression, the interpretation of the effect of x on y seems to be a bit more complicated. How could I report (read, explain) the effect of my independent variable (in the current case) in an elegant way?

I really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: As a comment that in no way is intended to answer your question - with ~739,400 observations and only 11 values of the independent variable, I personally wouldn't run any regression at all, I'd just use the mean of $y$ given each of the 11 values of $x$.  The standard errors of the $\bar{y}_i, i = 1, \dots, 11$ are going to be very small even with a quite uneven distribution of your samples across $i=1,\dots,11$, and I don't see that trying to force a parametric function on the data is adding anything of value.

Comment: To add to @jbowman's comment, you have so much data and the values of the independent variable are so limited that it is likely you could accurately estimate *the entire conditional distribution* for every one of the 11 independent values.  Moreover, it looks like the response actually is discrete: only a limited number of distinct values appears.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I hope anybody else try to answer. In the meantime, I've been trying to plot the conditional distribution by using cdplot. First time that I use it, and it looks good and it seems to facilitate the analysis of my data. I wonder if both quadratic regression and conditional density analysis can be run when having a discrete response (as shown in my dependent variable). Any limitation or "red line" on this?